# Meaning of "additive form"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I'm writing a inferential visual analysis and I'm not sure if the phrase "Additive form" makes sense. The phrase is meant to represent a persons added form (for example clothing). I'm using it in the sentence "The arrangement of the two delegations, their additive form and environment are a clarion representation of their symbiosis. ".

Regards,
Techhead55

Comment: Yes it should have been "are", just corrected it.

Comment: _clarion representation of their symbiosis_ seems like buzzworditis.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any particularly interesting usage of "additive form" after a quick internet search. If the term exists it is probably a technical term specific to a particular context.

You can choose to define the term for your own use in your analysis but, unfortunately, only your peers and colleagues will be able to tell you if the term makes sense. Here on EL&U we just don't have enough context or expertise to help answer the question.